# How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used here?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, decryption, cryptanalysis

Is there a way to find what type of encryption/encoding is being used? For example, I am working on php script they using this encryption to give the output URL to android apk

for example this out put come in

bwaBzc+KGa37EJnLiyOT9EunkcgYv7QQMezAfmmgo2us4Xk0F67pEoEPrxqXQcuzgrdxg99N4rNyjBzm32vD30OF8TMD8660n6Lu9TUkHuu4d4oAkuk5RIAQG+I+xSrozBym/BOsbVjmAlUi5qpwhI3VKrIo1S+SO1GxGiPntYHn9J9QVMTIrqZL2ebanwWgheixOZrpvH6HJsjtBs5yCf6rsv/fCXFVn9CISOk08eDxiWWv07BDUtUtvS+vQuDC6Zx5615gAtizHNOIFHXqRQdRusfymJ9w4YgMGO6QPYQ=

second respond will be 
the actual working url 
http://wpc.FC2A.edgecastcdn.net/80FC2A/ams2/app/229935.stream/playlist.m3u8?s2MrJMO2H7Jo0gKYJO8FXxBovtTtTNUvYV6gZFOFD0a9c9MSYkXrKuZ4W3BqrYgZVmDSC4cUjW5W5CrEHavS6IuX7na6xEL4tJteU1RQpjzO_GVZJctA32Nkq7A